# Iignore a bad CSV record in BigQuery

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

How can I skip bad records from a CSV file in BigQuery? I have tried using these functions:

```
configLoad.setMaxBadRecords(10);

configLoad.getMaxBadRecords();
```

I have one bad record in the input CSV. But the code returns `null` when I use the functions above and the code fails rather than ignoring the bad record.

Comment: could you give more info about how your csv record looks? maybe a sample record with their types would help to analyze better.

Comment: In the CSV file I have inserted one extra column.  like their should be 4 fields in the file but i have inserted one extra column.for example (abc,bcd,1,2,4)

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem here is in how to check for success vs error.

Jobs return their current status as:

```
  state: PENDING|RUNNING|DONE
  errorResult: { ... }
  errors: [{...}, {...}, ...]
```

When a job is in the `DONE` state, then `errorResult` determines whether the job was overall a success (no errorResult present) or failure (a structured error in the errorResult field).

The errors in the `errors` list will contain all fatal and non-fatal errors encountered.

Here is an example status result from a successfully completed load job that contained 1 bad row with a setMaxBadRecords(10) set on the load job configuration:

```
"status": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "location": "File: 0 / Line:1", 
        "message": "Too many columns: expected 2 column(s) but got 3 column(s). For additional help: http://goo.gl/RWuPQ", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  },
```

Without the setMaxResults, it would be a failing job as follows:

```
"status": {
    "errorResult": {
      "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.", 
      "reason": "invalid"
    }, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "location": "File: 0 / Line:1", 
        "message": "Too many columns: expected 2 column(s) but got 3 column(s). For additional help: http://goo.gl/RWuPQ", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }, 
      {
        "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  },
```